# ASP Classic SSI or execute?

Tags: asp-classic, include, session-variables

for a uni assignment I have to produce  a web system, in ASP Classic 3.0. I'm having trouble with a few important bits.

The system has 4 different user types: Admin, Customer, Photographer and a general user who is not logged in.

I have the headers in an include file. If an admin logs in, they have a different header, as they can access secure areas etc, ultimately I need a different header for each of the 4 user types.

The admin's header is currently only displaying on the secured pages, because the include simply includes that file.

I can't use an if statement to check if the condition of the session variable "user_type" is true and then include their header:  because of the way IIS deals with includes. It gets all 4 headers and outputs an error.

It appears that server.execute is the way to go, however, I am having trouble implementing it.

Any assistance or advice would be great.

Thanks, in advance

Comment: Couldn't you have separate include files for each user category, then you could use a conditional  (if...then) statement.

Comment: I have 4 include files, 1 for each user type. ive been trying to put the if statements within the page, so when a condition is met, it will include the file based on which user type was found to be true. But as includes are processed first, the if statement is only read after the includes have been rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to work

```
 If Session("user_type") = "Admin" Then 
    Server.Execute("adminheader.asp")
 ElseIf Session("user_type") = "Photographer" Then 
    Server.Execute("photographerheader.asp")
 ElseIf Session("user_type") = "Customer" Then 
    Server.Execute("customerheader.asp")
 Else
    Server.Execute("generalheader.asp")
 End If
```

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciated. Exactly what I needed.